# For $n\equiv1 \text{ (mod 101)}$, show that there does not exist a four-digit square number $n$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Prove that there does not exist a four-digit square number $n$ such that $n\equiv1   \text{ (mod 101)}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
n &= 1+101k= a^2, \quad a,k\in \mathbb Z \\[1em]
101k &= a^2-1 \\[1em]
&= (a-1)(a+1) \\[1em]
\end{align}
$$

$101$ is prime, and the lowest $k \in \mathbb Z$ that satisfies this is $99$. In this case, $n=1+101\cdot99=10000$.